# Combined Axes in jqPlot - centimeters & weight (axes values)

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqplot

I'm using jqPlot to render a growthchart. In this chart I have a line for weight and a line for centimeters.

Now my Problem: how do I combine those two kind of values?

The Y-Axe should start with the weight: 
`0.5, 1, 1.5, 2 .... 3.5, 4 [kg]`
and then continue with centimeters: `20,25,30,35,40,45,50,55,60... [cm]`
that I get an graph with this Y-Axe values:

`0.5, 1, 1.5, 2 .... 3.5, 4, 20, 25 ,30 ,35 ,40 ,45 ,50 ,55 ,60...`

I think I have to use the `$.jqplot.LinearAxisRenderer`, maybe the experimental function of breakPoints, but I'm not really shure about that at the moment.

Does someone have an idea - did you understand my problem?

Greetings Eldo.Ob